# How can I stop people accessing a plone server via webdav?

Tags: plone

I would like to know how I can disable webdav access to my `plone4 server`.  The server is configured to block all direct http access to the normal zope client ports (8080, and 8081), and it is impossible to access plone externally via the `http://ploneservername:8080` address.  This is intended as we want all client connections to be encrypted.  I have configured it so that all access has to be proxied via an `apache2` service running on the same server that listens/terminates SSL on port 443.  The standard zope listening ports (8080, 8081, 8100) are only configured to listen on the 127.0.0.1 address, they are not available from outside the box.  The apache service proxies all `SSL/443` traffic to `127.0.0.1:8080` which is what the zope client is listening on.

The only port that external clients can connect to on the box is 443 which is served by apache, and which proxies to the http/8080 address (via proxypass directive using the virtualhostmonster).  This all works perfectly.

The problem is that webdav clients are still able to connect to the box via `SSL/port443` and successfully authenticate and upload/download files.  This is the case even though the webdav port hasn't been opened / configured anywhere in the plone config files, and the server is not listening for webdav connections when viewed through netstat -ap.  I have been able to connect using 2 different webdav clients (bitkinex and win7 built-in), using the `https://ploneserveraddress URL`.  I was under the impression that webdav should only be available if it's been explicitly enabled via the zope instance sections of the config file.

Is there a way to completely shut down webdav access?  Simply ommiting it from the config files hasn't stopped us being able to connect using this method when going in via `apache/443/SSL`.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDAV runs on the same port (since 4.0?). In addition to any other Plone-internal solutions, you can configure your Apache to only allow some HTTP verbs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#limit . This helps insofar as a browser usually only generates GET and POST. (You might want to double-check with the AJAX-y editor features, though.)

Comment: Ah, had no idea this was the case with Plone4 as all the guides I'd found online seemed to indicate webdav had to be enabled on a seperate port (e.g. 1980).  Great info, thanks for clarifying, appreciate it.  :)

Comment: IIRC, webdav hasn't changed. The alternate port could be enabled to deliver content tailored to webdav — editing, for example — but the http ports always allowed the webdav actions.
In any case, Ulrich's suggestion to filter at your reverse proxy will do the trick.

Comment: WebDAV has *always* run on the same port ever since the feature was added to Zope.

Comment: There is a "WebDAV access" permission that is — by default — given to authenticated. You could try withdrawing it at the ZODB root.

Comment: Thanks for all the good info folks.  I ended up filtering as suggested by Ulrich and everything is working fine and as expected.