# How to prepare for mass file and page changes?

Tags: file, plone, push

How do I setup for an annual changeover of twenty pages with links to 500 PDFs in 10 different folders?

Here's an example of one of the pages in the annual changeover -
http://www6.hawaii.gov/tax/a1_b1_1income.htm

Here's information on the Plone I use -
Plone 3.2.2
CMF 2.1.2
Zope (Zope 2.10.7-final, python 2.4.5, linux2)
Python 2.4.5 (#1, Jun 12 2009, 14:44:23) [GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10)]
PIL 1.1.6

What I don't know - Is there another program like Enfold Desktop which allows mass uploads of files and folders to a Plone site?

I am disallowed Enfold Desktop because of it's need for WebDAV and port 80.

With Enfold Desktop I know it was possible to upload multiple folders or multiple files.

With that possibility, I could then, delete all the old folders and files, and all the old pages. Next, upload new folders with new files. And, finally, upload all the new pages with the correct links.

This is like SFTP, which when properly prepared, I comfortably completed the operations, within 10-15 minutes.

I think such tasks are outside the base Plone paradigm. I believe the Plone paradigm is to make it simple for one person to upload one file at a time while working on one page at time. And prevent errors.

I am hoping to do content management like Windows Explorer.

I could use some help on search terms at plone.org. I have tried "file management". I have tried "add multiple files".

Tried searching at Google and Yahoo on "Plone file management" and "Plone add multiple files". As well as "push files to Plone".
Tried stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/search
Tried all three search expressions at Blekko.

Thanks in advance,
Brian Kim
ITS III, Dept. of Taxation, State of Hawaii

Comment: The easiest way would be if you can convince your IT people to allow WebDAV access temporarily, for just your user. (This: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9127269/505649 might be useful.) 
A variation on the theme would be to make a copy of the database, run it on a separate installation which is not publicly accessible, do the WebDAV there, and then export+import the folder with your new stuff in it.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich Schwarz. I intend to monitor the thread for a bit. The link is useful. Over my head, but I sense the value. Another department has the responsibility of Zope, Plone, and Apache.

Answer (score 2):

A part from Plone's native webdav/ftp support that you excluded already for internal reasons, I can see some of solution for doing this out-of-the-box:

1. [atreal.massloader](http://plone.org/products/massloader) allows to do massive uploads via Zip files
2. [collective.quickupload](http://plone.org/products/collective.quickupload) allows to easly upload files using drag and drop, with a progress bar and uploading them with javascript or flash.
3. [Products.PloneFlashUpload](http://plone.org/products/ploneflashupload) adds an upload tab to folders which takes the user to an upload form

For a more flexible/advanced solution I'd suggest [collective.trasmogrifier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier). I'm confident that with a very little development and using already available blueprints (for ex. [transmogrify.filesystem](http://plone.org/products/transmogrify.filesystem) ), you could do a pipeline that automatically makes all the work like removing/moving old files , uploading new files from a specific source (for ex. from an internal webserver or a shared folder) and rebuilding links. And if you are an highly lazy person ( :P ) you could even add a cron that runs 1 time per year and executes that pipeline.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo Spettoli. I will look into the Products.